# Printing the paragraph containing a particular word in docx in python

Tags: python

I need to print the entire paragraph containing a particular word from a docx file using python.
I am attaching the code below which I have used. I am able to print the line in which it is present but not the entire paragraph. Can anybody help me with this?

```
!pip install python-docx 
import docx
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
file_name = 'Demo.docx'
doc = docx.Document(file_name)
print(doc.paragraphs)
word="Abrasives"

for p in doc.paragraphs:
    if(word in p.text):
      print(p.text)
```

It prints the line in which Abrasives is present.Does anybody has any solution please?

Below is the content of my Demo.docx.Please help if anyone knows anything

The demand for Super Abrasive products is closely linked to the level of industrial production. Super Abrasives are used to manufacture long-lasting, expensive items like auto and aircraft parts, demand for which is highly cyclical. Diamond and Cubic Boron
Nitride (CBN) Super Abrasive products are used extensively in aerospace industry and other industrial applications where price considerations are less significant as they incur high initial costs. They are used in the machining of materials such as nickel, cast iron and cobalt-based superalloys, where precision in machining operations is of prime importance.

Increasing complexity of Super Abrasive technology in high performance applications and its high initial cost make it difficult for small-scale and medium-scale companies to compete with the global market leaders. While industry leaders can afford significant research operations, most unorganized players do not have access to substantial R&D resources. This disparity can make it difficult for small and medium-scale companies to compete in the market, in terms of developing products that may require advanced technologies.

Comment: Have you considered that the `. docx` file might have a hard line break at the end of each line, with a blank line to indicate paragraphs? This is speculation, of course. Without your input it's impossible to be sure. But that is what your description suggests.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.text), `p.text` _should_ return all of the text in the paragraph. Are you sure your text is actually all in the same paragraph?

Comment: I have added the content of my docx. It has two paragraphs but it is printing only the line which contains abrasives